# sorting array and matching other array

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write a program where I write information of people like: name,minutes and seconds.I need to sort people by the time. I can't understand how to sort minutes and dont lose other array sequence order- name and second. they just stay standing where they stood.

```
#include <iostream>          
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct people{
int min[6], sec[6];
string name[6];
};
int main()
{
 int temp;
 people z;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
   cin>>z.name[i];
   cin>>z.min[i];
   cin>>z.sec[i];
 }
sort(z.min,z.min+6);
cout<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
    cout<<z.name[i]<<" "<<z.min[i]<<" "<<z.sec[i]<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}
/*Input for example is :

John 6 15  
Liza 9 59 
Michael 19 45 
Kira 2 37 
Thomas 5 41 
Justas 13 24 
/*
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand how structures and arrays should be used for this assignment. Instead of having a structure of arrays (which doesn't really make any sense in this case) you should have an array of structures.

Comment: oh, okay, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

So as Some programmer dude said you've gotta have an array of structs rather than a struct of arrays. But even after that you'll probably run into problems as you'll have to fill in an arguement called a functor/comparitor in the `sort` function. a much simpler way to do it would be if you used a `pair<int, pair<string, int> z[6]` and then directly use `sort(z, z+6)` after you input the required values into your array. This is because the sort function can sort an array of pair objects based on the first field(`int`) of the object in ascending order.To access the fields of each triplet in the array, you'll want use `z[i].first` for the first `int` field, `z[i].second.first` for the second string field and `z[i].second.second` for the final int field. 
Note that a comparitor or functor is a method to help define an ordering between two objects that are not a `string` or an `int` or any other standard objects. See these for more information: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functors-in-cpp/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-vector-in-c/.